# Will session gets timed out when request taking time to load

Tags: java, session, web

In web.xml I've mentioned 5mins as the session time out.
Suppose if my request to load page with data from db taked morethan 5 mins what will happen.
Will the request get processed ? will the sessiong timeout get extended?

Comment: First point - requests probably shouldn't take 5 minutes... But the request will still get processed, the session might well get timed out though.

Answer (score 0):

The session is attached with a timestamp generate on the server. This timestamp is used by the server to know if the session is timeout.

So when you'll access the session in this process or an other, if the timer is ended, the session will be out of date even if it is caused by a too long processing of the last request.

Answer (score 0):

It will expire, as there is no communication happening between client and server. On the other hand, for these kind of long-running jobs, it is better to use some sort of async/batch technology, and let the client check results later.